# How to delete popup window in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

I have a sequence of pop up windows. I intended to close the window once i have completed the desired task. I am using a "askokcancel" button to get users confirmation whether the activity has completed. The problem is, every time the user presses ok, the focus goes back to the main starting window and rest of the pop up windows goes to the background while staying active. I want to either close the pop up windows or keep the focus to the second last window. Below is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, StringVar, messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from mytest import *
from tkinter import *
        
class myclass:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame1, text = 'select me first', width = 25, command = self.buttonFunc)
        self.button1.pack()
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame1, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.close_windows1)
        self.quitButton.pack()
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.master.geometry("200x200+60+60")
        
    def buttonFunc(self):
        self.top = tk.Toplevel(self.master)                       
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.top,text="Select second",command=self.anotherButtonFunc)
        self.button2.pack()
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.top, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.close_windows2)
        self.quitButton.pack() 
        self.master.geometry("200x200+60+60")

    def anotherButtonFunc(self):    

        self.top2 = tk.Toplevel(self.top)
        self.newClass = myClassExt(self.top2)
        
    def close_windows1(self):
        self.master.destroy() 
        
    def close_windows2(self):
        self.top.destroy() 

class myClassExt():
    def __init__(self, top2):
        self.top3 = top2
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self.top3)
        self.button3 = tk.Button(self.frame2, text = 'select me third', width = 25, command = self.buttonFunc)
        self.button3.pack()
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame2, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.close_windows4)
        self.quitButton.pack()
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.top3.geometry("200x200+60+60")

    def buttonFunc(self):        
        ok = messagebox.askokcancel(message='Press OK to Confirm?')
        if not ok:
            pass
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Success","Well done")
            self.close_windows4()
            
    def close_windows4(self):
        self.top3.destroy() 
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    myclass = myclass(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

From this made up example, i somehow want to either close window number 2 after user presses OK or keep the focus on window 2 rather than window 1. Please guide

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to close a message box, although you can easily make your own. You just have to make a new tkinter window, and set an image, title, and text, then add a close button, and return the tk window. I made a function like this myself, for this very reason. Here is the function:

```py
def mymessage(title, text, spacing = 25, buttonText = "Close", image = None):
    tk2 = Tk()
    tk2.resizable(0, 0)
    tk2.title(title)
    if image != None:
        image = Label(tk2, image = PhotoImage(file = image))
        image.pack()
    spacer = Frame(tk2, relief = FLAT, bd = 0, width = 200, height = 25)
    spacer.pack()
    label = Label(tk2, text = text)
    label.pack()
    button = Button(tk2, text = buttonText, width = 5, height = 1, command = tk2.destroy)
    button.pack()
    return tk2
```

After calling the function, it returns the tk window, for easy destruction.

Comment: You shouldn't create a new ```Tk()``` object; ```Toplevel()``` works better.